# rails 3 routting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Working on rails 3 project in my routes

```
get 'floor_view/floor_view_history' => "floor_views#floor_view_history", :as => "floor_view_history"
```

then I change to

```
get 'floor_views/floor_view_history' => "floor_views#floor_view_history", :as => "floor_view_history"
```

changing to floor_views from floor_view

then restart the server and try to go to the same path showing error

```
Started GET "/floor_views/floor_view_history" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 17:44:13 +0530
AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'show' could not be found for       FloorViewsController: actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:116:in `process'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have in your routes.rb line like:

```
resources :floor_views
```

When Rails routing system meets this line, it assumes that you want to call `show` action, which is not implemented, as error message says. One of the way to fix this is to change this line to:

```
resources :floor_views, except: :show
```

This won't produce path to `show` action.

Comment: It's working but can you please tell me what I have change I just change the controller name and then restart the server so why this problem is coming which is previously not coming.